# Rolling in xts time series

Tags: r, xts

I want to calculate a weekly (end of every week) rolling mean of the last month. 
Exactly: Assume that the time series don't include any weekand. So what I mean is that I would start every Friday and calculate the mean of the last month.

- Friday 2018-07-06: mean of `2018-07-06 - 2018-06-06`
- Friday 2018-07-13: mean of `2018-07-13 - 2018-06-13`
- Friday 2018-07-20: mean of `2018-07-20 - 2018-06-20`

Two important things:

1. I have to define really the starting day (e.g. Friday). What I mean is that I couldn't say n=7 because sometimes it could occur that in the time series one week is missing.
2. I couldn't say change the number of the month `07`to `06`because it also occur that `2018-06-20`itn't included in the time series.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)